# my normal map is giving me these issues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

i did my textures in substance painter and imported into blender however blender is giving me these results but i didn't see this in substance painter, I don't know what is wrong  [image: texture issues in picture and node i did]

Answer (score 0):

Textures made in Substance Painter use DirectX to generate normals (by default), as opposed to blender which uses OpenGL. To make the normal maps look correct, often you need to do a *DirectX to OpenGL* conversion on the Normal texture - done by inverting the Y axis direction (blue channel) - shown below:

[image: Conversion]